# Installing ceiling fan light kit if switch housing cover plate has no hole

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

I have had a ceiling fan for some time in my front room, but no light installed.  To combat darkness during the winter, I am ready to try to make it happen by buying a ceiling fan light kit.

The tutorials I have watched thus far involve removing the switch housing cover plate and then at some point feeding the wires through the hole in that cover plate, however the plate that was on mine has no such hole.  It has the notch on the side to line up with the switch for the fan and it has three screws about 120 degrees apart from each other on the sides, but other than that it is solid.

So before buying a light kit, I want to make sure that I can actually complete the installation.  Is this lack of hole going to be a problem, and if so, what can I do to resolve the situation?

**EDIT**

Well, the fan was installed already when I moved in, so I did not do it myself.  It is a Hampton Bay and by using the mirror and a flashlight and reading upside down writing on the top of the fan, I think the model is CD-5201.  It has some sort of moon pattern on each of the 5 blades, but I am sure that does not help.

But here are the requested pictures:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

Fast-forwarding in time, I used flashlight and *smartphone* to capture the information.

- UPC = 759590966714
- Vendor = 23827 - Aloha Breeze after talking with Hampton Bay customer service
- Date = 9711

I am guessing that it 1997?  Oh, brother!  The fan works perfectly though.

Comment: What model ceiling fan is it?  Can you post a photo of the cover plate?

Comment: Oh, and wouldn't you know it, I was at Lowe's like 45 minutes ago.  Whoops, wrong store.

Comment: Talking with a man at Home Depot, it appears that the current covers (even the universal ones) are of a larger size.  He thinks that it might not necessarily be too pretty to look at to attempt installation of the ones the kits they currently have in stock.

Answer (score 3):

The light kit might just replace this cover. So you'll take off this cover plate, and install the light kit in its place.

Comment: I have installed light kits on a half-dozen Hunter fans. The bottom plate comes off and the light kit has instructions for what to do.